# Athena partition projection not displaying any data for current year

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a partition projection built to generate an athena table off of some data in a year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD partition format. It worked perfectly for 2023, but in 2024 it is displaying nothing (data cuts off on 2023-12-31).

Here is the create table that I used:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `eskimi.eskimi_3pct_sample`(
  `idfa` string, 
  `exchangeid` int, 
  `app` string, 
  `devicemodelid` int, 
  `deviceosid` int, 
  `devicetypeid` int, 
  `useragent` string, 
  `mccmnc` string, 
  `primarymccmnc` string, 
  `connectiontype` int, 
  `country` string, 
  `lat` double, 
  `lon` double, 
  `ip` string, 
  `timestamp` bigint, 
  `yob` int, 
  `gender` string, 
  `dnt` int, 
  `hwv` string, 
  `deviceos` string, 
  `deviceosv` string, 
  `devicemake` string, 
  `devicemodel` string, 
  `carrier` string, 
  `accuracy` int, 
  `locationtype` int, 
  `ipservice` int, 
  `language` string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` int, 
  `month` int, 
  `day` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://c400-athena-dev-comlinkdata-com/client_projects/location/eskimi/three_percent_sample_eskimi'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'parquet.compress'='snappy', 
  'projection.day.format'='dd', 
  'projection.day.range'='01,31', 
  'projection.day.type'='integer', 
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.month.format'='MM', 
  'projection.month.range'='01,12', 
  'projection.month.type'='integer', 
  'projection.year.format'='yyyy', 
  'projection.year.range'='2023,2040', 
  'projection.year.type'='integer', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://c400-athena-dev-comlinkdata-com/client_projects/location/eskimi/three_percent_sample_eskimi/year=${year}/month=${month}/day=${day}', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1707118281')
```

I've checked the s3 location for the 2024 data and everything looks good, an example uri is `s3://c400-athena-dev-comlinkdata-com/client_projects/location/eskimi/three_percent_sample_eskimi/year=2024/month=01/day=01/`

and they all follow that format, which is exactly what I'd expect. However, in the Athena table, there is nothing for any day past 2023. I tried recreating the table using just 2024 data, and it creates an empty table. I've tried `msck repair table` (I know it shouldn't make a difference in parition projection) and while it gives me the notification that those dates in 2024 have been added to the metadata, the result is still a table with no values for 2024 data.

I pulled some of the parquets into Python and there is nothing different about them from 2023, the schema is the same. Can't see any reason this would be happening.

Comment: Did you try to update the partitions with `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`. Check other ideas here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't affect partition projections. I spoke with someone at AWS and they're doing a deeper investigation on this.

As a temporary workaround, I've remade the table no longer as a partition projection, and that works as expected. I'll post updates here if I hear back from aws.